# Removing form validation causes form not to submit?

Tags: forms, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.5

I've removed pretty much all .js references in my Magento theme. Specifically I've removed the  onclick from the add to cart button.

in `template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml` I've removed `onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)`

in `template/catalog/product/view/view.phtml` I removed this block of code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
    if (this.validator.validate()) {
        var form = this.form;
        var oldUrl = form.action;

        if (url) {
           form.action = url;
        }
        var e = null;
        try {
            this.form.submit();
        } catch (e) {
        }
        this.form.action = oldUrl;
        if (e) {
            throw e;
        }

        if (button && button != 'undefined') {
            button.disabled = true;
        }
    }
}.bind(productAddToCartForm);

productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
    if(this.validator) {
        var nv = Validation.methods;
        delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
        delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
        delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
            if (url) {
                this.form.action = url;
            }
            this.form.submit();
        }
        Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
    }
}.bind(productAddToCartForm);
//]]>
</script>
```

However, now when I submit the form I get nothing.

I figured to change the add to cart `<button>` to a proper submit. So I changed this....

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
```

to this ...

```
 <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" />
```

When I do that, the form submits but I get a "Page Not Found", the URL it takes me to looks like this `/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzcwLjMyLjc0LjQ2L3J0bF9tYWdlbnRvL2luZGV4LnBocC9jYXRhbG9nL3Byb2R1Y3Qvdmlldy9pZC8xNQ,,/product/15/`

Is it not possible to submit a form the old fashioned way in Magento without javascript? If it is, can you give some pointers?

My plan was to hook up my own jQuery validation (which is quite simple, I just need to validate that the qty field has length) and ditch some of the ridiculousness of the code above.

Comment: Don't you think when you add jquery to the page where prototype is loaded and when you replace prototype validation with jquery one (instead of adding needed validation rule to the input field class attribute) looks even more ridiculousness?

Comment: Not really. I would need 2 or 3 lines of code to validate what I need instead of 30. Plus, site wide I will be using jQuery and not prototype. So it makes perfect sense actually. u mad?

Comment: And to add to that... When I write my validation I'll actually **comment** the code. Then when I go to update it in another 6 months I'll know what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how and I don't know why, but when I disable "Use Web Server Rewrites" it works with the standard submit button.

[image]